# Error when using javac: "javac: invalid flag: -s"

Tags: maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to specify another version of JDK in `maven-compiler-plugin`. When `-target` and `-source` parameters are set to 1.5, everything is ok. But when i try to use 1.6 JDK, maven reports an error. Has anyone faced this problem?

Error:

> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>   javac: invalid flag: -s
>   Usage: javac  
>   where possible options include:
>   -g                         Generate all debugging info
>   -g:none                    Generate no debugging info

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your pom so we could see which version of the compiler plugin you're using and how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use 1.6 flag your JAVA_HOME should point to JDK 1.6.

Check it with java -version on a command line.

To define your JAVA_HOME do this:

Add to your `~/.bashrc` this line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

reference: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/