# Maven compilation error. Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:javac: invalid flag: -s

Tags: java, maven

I am getting a compilation error when try to execute mvn clean install.

```
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
    javac: invalid flag: -s
    Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 11:31:09-0600)
Maven home: C:\Sajith\apache-maven-3.0.3\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.5.0_16, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
    <description>TestApp Release 1.0 Build</description>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>TestApp API</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that output of java --version or maven -version . It could happen that this could be different.

Comment: what is the output of mvn -version ?

Comment: Maven version is   Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 11:31:09-0600)
Maven home: C:\Sajith\apache-maven-3.0.3\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.5.0_16, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Comment: In that case check my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your maven is using java 5 (as your comment says). You have to change your  JAVA_HOME variable to point to jdk 6 or higher. Look at :

[Error when using javac: "javac: invalid flag: -s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328677/error-when-using-javac-javac-invalid-flag-s)

Comment: Yes.This is working.Thanks a lot.Once quick doubt is the maven require jdk 6 or higher?

Comment: In general it doesn't. If you use java version 1.6 (which you are doing based on the comments here) in your pom.xml then you need jdk 6 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i dont have the apropiate environment variable because the project is inherited, and I had not created the variable JDK_WAS85_JDK8 = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221.
Usually is JAVA_HOME the variable that is set.
[image: father pom.xml]