# Maven compilation error while giving the clean install command

Tags: maven

I tried with the command `mvn clean install` in cmd prompt. But I keep getting the following compilation error

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
```

I am using MyEclipse 2016, jdk 1.5.0_22, Maven-2.2.1
Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733171/maven-compilation-error-failure-executing-javac-but-could-not-parse-the-error

Comment: Thank you @Avinash

Comment: That works ! Thanks again.

Comment: Migrate to Maven 3.X cause [Maven 2. is End of Live](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise sure. Migration will be done soon.