# Intellij IDEA: Maven JDK for importer setting is not respected

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am seeing a few Java/maven projects failing to be parsed, built, and/or run in intellij.  Below is shown one of the issues encountered:

[image]

Note that I did manually change the setting as shown in the warning:

[image]

But the error still occurs.   Any insights on how to fix this?

**Update** This does build on the command line via

```
 mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your jdk and the maven version are not compatible. In such cases, so parse errors can happen.

Comment: Thx for making me see that I did not mention in the OP:  this is building properly on the command line; therefore,maven and  java are happy together.  The OP has been updated.

Comment: I have found some links, I hope they will help. Otherwise, you may build your project with -X command, and share the output with use. The links are

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328677/error-when-using-javac-javac-invalid-flag-s

Comment: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200811.mbox/%3C20684404.post@talk.nabble.com%3E

Comment: @BernhardColby how to know which jdk is compatible with the maven?